# Indeterminate Progress Bar issues with dismissing it in wrong thread, error:android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I will start with my final outcome that I would like to acheive and give you what I have done and then things that I have tried.

Final Outcome is to have a pdf file download and display on screen in a fragment.  Have a Indefinite Progress Bar spinning while the pdf is downloading and loading to screen.  When document is loaded to screen dismiss the progress bar.  Because the progress bar disappears before the pdf is displayed add about 5 seconds to it.

So with my current code on the devices that I have tested it works beautifully.  However after letting others test it, it crashes and we get android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException.

So here is the current code that on some devices causes the above error:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
    PDFView pdfView;
    ProgressBar simpleProgressBar;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        pdfView = getView().findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        new RetrievePDFStream().execute("http://gator3067.temp.domains/~kazack/app/Menu.pdf");
    }

    class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void, InputStream> {


        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            simpleProgressBar = getView().findViewById(R.id.simpleProgressBar);
            simpleProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream((urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream){
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        // Do some work here
                        sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    // start next intent
                    new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            // Dismiss the Dialog
                            simpleProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            // start selected activity
                            }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();




        }

    }
}
```

So in my new revised code I already made one adjustment, which is inregards to accessing UI in background.  So I moved the 2 following lines from background to PreExecute method:

```
simpleProgressBar = getView().findViewById(R.id.simpleProgressBar);
simpleProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Now I do understand the error which is you can not access it from a thread that did not start it to begin with.  Which in my code I am creating a new thread and trying to dismiss it that way.  Which will throw the exception error on some devices.

So after reading some more, I found out that instead of using new Thread that I should be using:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
```

So I rewrote my code to do that and what happens is the indeterminate does not spin and just sits there doing nothing and still disappears fairly quickly.

So as a temporary solution I changed OnPostExecut to:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream){
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();

            simpleProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        }
```

Now all is good, however I do not get the indefinite progress bar to run an additional 5 seconds like I get with my original code, which is apparently wrong because it crashes on some devices.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciative, again overall goal is to take what I have and add 5 additional seconds to the progress bar before dismissing it.

I did not know if there is a way to dismiss it from one thread while in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe issue is now resolved.  After typing in everything above a thought hit me, so I tried it and walah it worked.  Created the apk and ran it on a working device and also ran it on a device that was crashing.  And both work beautifully.

So the end result was changing the onPostExecute from

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream){
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        // Do some work here
                        sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    // start next intent
                    new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            // Dismiss the Dialog
                            simpleProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            // start selected activity
                            }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

to:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream){
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        // Do some work here
                        sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    // start next intent
                   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           // Dismiss the Dialog
                           simpleProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           // start selected activity
                       }
                   }); {

                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

I can't approve my own solution, but if someone can confer that this is the right way to do it, or show a better way to do it I would be more than greatful.